# SP Designer >> Adding custom New Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, redirect

1. From the SP Designer, I went to the Survey List
2. Add a form "type == new" survey.aspx
3. On "Finish" button for RedirectUrl I put "http://ip.cisco.com/pages/Thankyou.aspx"
4. Saved the form
5. Went to take a survey and redirect does not work
6. Came back to SP Designer and RedirectUrl value is gone
7. Also the "Toolbar" is present in the survey.aspx form
8. The width of the survey.aspx form is 100% unlike newform.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to create a link to the survey's NewForm.aspx page with a querystring parameter on it.

```
http://ip.cisco.com/lists/survey/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://ip.cisco.com/pages/Thankyou.aspx
```

Comment: I followed sp guy suggestion and it worked. but the new form "sNewForm.aspx" looks weird. The width is same as windows width and even stretched to the right. It has the tool bars as well. But the build in NewForm.aspx looks nice and don't have tool bar. how do I take care of the cosmetic issue with the custom new form.

Comment: Look in the code of the custom form, you can remove the tool bar and you probably need to tweak the web part zone width to be static and not 100%.

Comment: Tool bar still shows up and I have the width to be static but still it's taking full window's width.